Problem with Hair particles when combing

Basically, I have a big problem with hair particles as for some reason they are not acting fully symmetrical but just when I comb them and not affecting to the whole mesh. I have already done the following steps:
-My mesh is in the center, fully symmetrical. I checked using SHIFT + CTRL + M
-I have applied all transforms.
-I have added particles on top of any modifier.
-My mesh has not loose geometry or doubles.
-Normals are all fine.
-My geometry is very well optimized.
-It does create the hair particles fully symmetrical but when I comb them, for some reason, they do not act symmetrical on X.
-In the image, you can see how I have brushed all my particles backwards on +X side and obviously -X side did it automatically but hair does not act symmetrical.
I am a bit desperated because I cannot find a solution to this issue anywhere. Is anyone able to help me?
Thanks.
Oscar G.


